# "Turbo" mode engaged continuously

Tags: msi, turbo-boost

I have an MSI ge60 0nd and I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

There is a light on my laptop that shows that I'm running in "Turbo" mode.

When I was using Windows the light turned on when needed but under Ubuntu it is on all time.

*How can I fix this?*

Comment: Can you describe the problem in more detail?

Comment: What do you mean by turbo mode?

Comment: Sure.There is a "turbo" button next to the power button.It shows computers performance.In windows,It lights only when i was playing games.In ubuntu,it lights even when there aren't any open programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Turbo" mode on your MSI laptop means that the NVidia card is activated and that full 3D performance is available to you at all time.

There are 2 possible ways to "fix" this:

1. Go into your BIOS and disable the NVidia card.  This will prevent Ubuntu from loading the NVidia driver and turn off the "Turbo" mode.  To enable it again, reboot, go into the BIOS again and enable the NVidia card.
2. If you want to enable the NVidia card *only for certain applications*, head to the [Bumblebee project](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee) and read the documentation to enable the NVidia driver for certain applications only...

*I wouldn't "fix" anything:* you have full performance available *at all time* and unless you travel a lot using your battery, I would use "System 1" (which is what I'm using now to write this message)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)